# iostream file not found in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, iostream

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A7sT.png)

I did use `<iostream>` as recommended in some answers, but it still says iostream is missing.

Comment: Give the source file a .cpp extension - it is currently being compiled as C code.

Comment: Sorry, I just started C++ today so I still don't know much

Comment: Also you don't need `std::cout` just `cout` as you are using the namespace `std`.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName But, [one shouldn't use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius But, if one uses it, he should use it properly :-)

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName That's the thing - one shouldn't use it. Read the linked question.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I think for learning c++ it doesn't really hurt one in the beginning.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName I disagree. The (anti-)patterns learned, while learning the language, are harder to unlearn.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName : neither does it hurt to learn the right thing from day 1.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius ok :-)

Answer (score 1):

1.you have created the project as c program please select c++ in code blocks
(ref screen shot)

2.Download and install only the file with name 
codeblocks mingw-setup.exe.(since mingw complier will be installed automatically).

3.try reinstalling code:blocks

and you need not use std before cout

since you have used the using namespace std; statement

[see the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oT7O.jpg)

hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

Console says: "No such files or directory" and "Compiler Unknown".

The missing header **iostream** is delivery by any compiler package. So, probably, you do not installed it or you configured it badly.